# Hashmap not showing previously added strings

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I am working on adding a `String` key and `String` value to a `hashmap1`. In turn, I also have to add that `hashmap1` to another `hashmap2` as a value whose key is a `String`.

Somehow, the `hashmap1` is overwriting the values for all the keys with the last added value. How do I resolve this to get `hashmap1` which contains all the value pairs that I added. `Al` is an `ArrayList` which contains the values that I am adding to the `hashmap1`.

```
    al.add("def");
    al.add("xyz");
    al.add("pqr");
    al.add("mno");  
    for(int i=0; i<al.size();i++){
        map.put("positionTitle", al.get(i).toString());
        System.out.println(map.get("positionTitle"));
        positionTitles.put(String.valueOf(i), map);
        System.out.println("Value in the position title while in the loop "+positionTitles.get(String.valueOf(i)).get("positionTitle"));
    }

    for(String s: positionTitles.keySet()){
        System.out.println("key in the position title:" +s);
        for(String a: positionTitles.get(s).keySet()){
        System.out.println("Keys in the map in the position title "+a);
        System.out.println("Values in the map in position title "+positionTitles.get(s).get(a));
        }
    }
```

Output:

> [abc, def, xyz, pqr, mno]
>
> abc
>
> Value in the position title while in the loop abc
>
> def
>
> Value in the position title while in the loop def
>
> xyz
>
> Value in the position title while in the loop xyz
>
> pqr
>
> Value in the position title while in the loop pqr
>
> mno
>
> Value in the position title while in the loop mno
>
> key in the position title:0
>
> Keys in the map in the position title positionTitle
>
> Values in the map in position title mno
>
> key in the position title:1
>
> Keys in the map in the position title positionTitle
>
> Values in the map in position title mno
>
> key in the position title:2
>
> Keys in the map in the position title positionTitle
>
> Values in the map in position title mno
>
> key in the position title:3
>
> Keys in the map in the position title positionTitle
>
> Values in the map in position title mno
>
> key in the position title:4
>
> Keys in the map in the position title positionTitle
>
> Values in the map in position title mno

Comment: It's very unclear? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: You always put in "positionTitle"(key) the value you are iterating over al, so when the first for loop ends, it saved only the value of the last item in "al" which is mno. That's why it overwrites with the last value. If you don't change the key, it will always save the values in the same key (map.put("positionTitle", al.get(i).toString()) saves always the al.get(i) in "positionTitle" key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the "map" variable is reused.

```
map.put("positionTitle", al.get(i).toString());
positionTitles.put(String.valueOf(i), map);
```

setts a new value for the same key in the same hashmap each time, and then stores the same object for different keys in the second map. Thus basically overwriting what you did before in each loop.
To solve your problem you would need to either create a new hashmap object for each loop or use different keys.
Since you talk about nested hashmaps I guess what you want to do is:

```
map = new HashMap();
map.put("positionTitle", al.get(i).toString());
positionTitles.put(String.valueOf(i), map);
```

I do not understan *why* you want to do this but good luck any way.